How can I make my thesis 1.5 line spaced
I am currently compiling my thesis, and am having trouble making it 1.5 line spaced. As you can see below, I have loaded the setspace' package yet the onehalfspacing' command is not working as I get an 'uncontrolled sequence' warning.
Please help me set the entire document as 1.5 line spaced.
Thank you.

% !TEX root = ./dissertation.tex
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX spellcheck = en-US
% !BIB TS-program = = biber
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,american,openright,final]{memoir}
% Documentclass options:
% "draft" for draft mode (quicker build)
% "showtrims" to show trimmed sides before printing
\usepackage{SSEThesisPreamble}

\title{Essays on structural transformation and gender equality in Vietnam}
\newcommand\thesubtitle{Dissertation for the Degree of Doctor of Philosophy, Ph.D., \\ in Economics}
\author{Anri~Sakakibara} % Use ~ instead of space to prevent line breaking

% Load the layout
\usepackage{SSEThesisLayout}

% All included chapters need to have their graphics paths specified manually here
% this is for input to work and to find the right figures
% Graphics paths for all documents
\graphicspath{{./chapters/chapter1/}{./chapters/chapter2/}{./chapters/chapter3/}}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\g@addto@macro\input@path{{./chapters/chapter1/}{./chapters/chapter2/}{./chapters/chapter3/}}%
\makeatother

% Bibliographies (can be multiple files)
\addbibresource{chapters/MyLibrary1.bib}
\addbibresource{chapters/MyLibrary.bib}
\addbibresource{chapters/trump_bib.bib}


% Include setspace package for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
% Set line spacing to 1.5
\onehalfspacing

\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TITLE PAGE (right side)
\vspace*{4\onelineskip}
\begin{center}
{\Huge\thetitle}\par\vspace*{2\onelineskip}
{\Large\thesubtitle}\par\vspace*{2\onelineskip}
{\Large\theauthor}\par
\end{center}

\vfill

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2.88cm]{KCL_logo.png}
\end{center}

\pagebreak

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Copyright page (on left side)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{m{1.93cm}X}
\includegraphics[width=1.93cm]{KCL_logo.png} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Dissertation for the Degree of Doctor of Philosophy, Ph.D.,\\
    in Economics\\
    King's College London, 2024\\
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{flushleft}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Acknowledgements
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{chapters/acknowledgements}\par\bigskip
\begin{center}
\emph{London, \\
June 2024}\par\smallskip
\emph{\theauthor}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Table of contents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents*% star for no TOC in TOC
\clearpage%
\mainmatter% change numbering to arabic

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% INTRODUCTION
\begin{refsection}
\chapter*{Introduction}\thispagestyle{empty}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}\markboth{Introduction}{}
\input{chapters/introduction}
\end{refsection}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CHAPTER 1
\begin{refsection}
    \chapter{The impact of the Vietnam War on female labour market outcomes}
    \begin{abstract}\input{chapters/chapter1/abstract}\end{abstract}%
    \include{chapters/chapter1/mainmatter} % include puts clearpages around automatically
    \begin{subappendices}
        % "fake" new chapter to get the unnumbered chapter style for appendix (also does a cleardoublepage)
        \SSEfakechapter{}{References}\SSEprintbibliography{none}
            \SSEfakechapter{}{Appendix}%
        \input{chapters/chapter1/appendix} % need to use input to not clearpage
    \end{subappendices}
\end{refsection}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CHAPTER 2
\begin{refsection}
    \chapter{Trade-induced structural transformation and household-level inequality: Lessons from Vietnam}
    \begin{abstract}\input{chapters/chapter2/abstract}\end{abstract}%
    \blindfootnote{This document is an output from the research initiative ‘Structural Transformation and Economic Growth’ (STEG), a programme funded by the Foreign, Commonwealth \& Development Office (FCDO), contract reference STEG\_LOA\_734\_Sakakibara. The views expressed are not necessarily those of FCDO.}%
    \include{chapters/chapter2/mainmatter} % include puts clearpages around automatically
    \begin{subappendices}
        % "fake" new chapter to get the unnumbered chapter style for appendix (also does a cleardoublepage)
        \SSEfakechapter{}{References} \SSEprintbibliography{none}
            \SSEfakechapter{}{Appendix}%
        \input{chapters/chapter2/appendix} % need to use input to not clearpage
    \end{subappendices}
\end{refsection}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CHAPTER 3
\begin{refsection}
    \chapter{Trade Policy and Jobs in Vietnam: Large The Unintended Consequences of Trump's Trade War}
    \begin{abstract}\input{chapters/chapter3/abstract}\end{abstract}%
    \blindfootnote{This paper is co-authored with Lorenzo Rotunno, Sanchari Roy and Pierre-Louis V\'ezina . This paper was supported by a British Academy/Leverhulme Small Research Grant.}%
    \include{chapters/chapter3/mainmatter} % include puts clearpages around automatically
    \begin{subappendices}
        % "fake" new chapter to get the unnumbered chapter style for appendix (also does a cleardoublepage)
        \SSEfakechapter{}{References} \SSEprintbibliography{none}
            \SSEfakechapter{}{Appendix}%
            \input{chapters/chapter3/appendix}
    \end{subappendices}
 \end{refsection}

\end{document}



Doesn't memoir instead implement its own version of setspace? Maybe try \OnehalfSpacing.

Welcome! If you look in the log or on the terminal, you'll find a message telling you setspace is 'emulated' by memoir. Unfortunately, it appears to emulate it somewhat imperfectly and doesn't actually provide the same commands. Hence, you need the camel case version.
